# Как создать новостной блог с возможностью добавления постов? HTML/Css/Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, блог

Нужна помощь в создании новостной ленты, а именно в добавлении новостных постов. Т.е в некой форме заполнялись данные, добавлялась фотография и затем по нажатию на кнопку содержимое отображалось на странице. 
Есть ли какие-нибудь примеры, как это сделать это не используя фреймворки js? Хотелось бы просто понять принцип написания блога.

Comment: `js` в браузере (клиент) не знает ничего об ОС, следовательно он может хранить данные только в `куках`, `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` => отсюда следует что когда вы заполните все ваши поля, то не сможете их запомнить (можно попытаться сделать это в куках - но это издевательство). Что касается сессии и локал хранилищ - то они вытруться как только вы перегрузите сайт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Блог нельзя сделать только на указанных вами технологиях. Вы перечислили только фронтенд. А для блога нужно где-то хранить данные, проводить авторизацию пользователей и так далее. Фреймворки JS тут не при чём, можно обойтись и без них при простых задачах (раньше делали без JS). Вместо самописного блога лучше возьмите готовый, так вы избежите огромного количества проблем (например с безопасностью). Обычно используют Вордпресс. Иначе вам придётся изучать не только указанное вами, но и PHP, MySQL или другие серверные языки.

Comment: в принципе сервак можно на js написать )

Comment: Точно ). Но думаю автор вопроса имел в виду JS на клиенте, а не ноду. Иначе бы не задавал такой вопрос.

Comment: И еще момент. Если человек знает js, то я думаю лучше разобраться за недельку с `php`, чем юзать `WP`. и вообще...я бы не советовал садиться за `WP `не зная `php`, и не прочтя как минимум 50% документации по нем...а то там такого можно наворотить с незнания. А `WP` - это достаточно сложный движок

Comment: Я имел в виду, что WP можно взять и блог готов, а не то, что на нём нужно программировать.